# Most efficient way to use arrays in MySQL statements?

Tags: php, string

Alright, take this for example:

```
$array['key'] = 'value';

$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='{$array[key]}'";
```

That's how I've been doing it, but of course if I were to enable E_ALL error reporting, I'd get a notice about using the undeclared constant, and it would assume 'key' instead of a constant.

As such, I assume that's not the proper or more efficient way to do it, so what would be the most efficient way of doing that SQL query (or other relevant string)?

Comment: I'd suggest switching to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or even `sprintf`

Comment: @AaronW. Yeah, I've just been putting it off. I guess now that I'm starting a new project that it's a good a time as any to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, if you lookup the PHP string quoting rules, if you omit the quotes around the key inside `{}` it will be interpreted as a constant.  However, if you omit the `{}` and the quotes, a simple array index will be properly interpreted without issuing a notice.

[PHP double-quoted string parsing rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) (The relevant examples are in the Variable Parsing section)

I tend to prefer surrounding with `{}` for readability:

```
// Inside {}, you must quote the array key or it will be interpreted as a constant
$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='{$array['key']}'";
```

But this is also valid and should not issue notices:

```
// Without {}, don't quote the array key and it will be correctly parsed.
$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='$array[key]'";
```

**Note that *the best way* to pass variables into SQL queries is to use an API that supports prepared statements instead of concatenating in variables**

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks! EDIT: Oh fooey. I can't accept the answer for another three minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote key.

```
$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='{$array['key']}'";
```

Comment: Yes, but correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that produce an unexpected string? Last time I tried that, that's what happened. Granted, that was probably a year or so ago, so maybe it changed or something else.

Comment: No, Michael explained it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to do it that way:

```
$SQL = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column='".$array['key']."'";
```

and I have never run in trouble with that.

If you re-use the sql, binding would be an advantage:

```
http://nz.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
```

HTH